# How to alternate by rows and 2 rows using CSS

Tags: css, angular

I have a requirements to display the data in the UI with the ffg scenarios:

1. Alternate colors by row if I select Capital see image below

[image: alternate colors every row]

2. Alternate colors in every two rows if I select Country and capital see image below.

[image: alternate colors every 2 rows]

How can I manipulate this using css and angular?

Comment: use css sudo class "odd" & "Even"

Comment: @SumitPatel, what about the alternate colors for 2 rows?

Comment: in that case you have to add one class to to the each 2 & 3 row

Comment: try this "https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mZmzog"

Comment: @SumitPatel, can you please send me a sample implementation?

Comment: just posted an example.

Comment: How do you select capital and country? Is it from a dropdown or by clicking that table data Capital City & Country?

Comment: @gosi123,  from dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check it out please. its the exact solution what your are looking for.

```css
.table1 tr:nth-child(2n){
  background: red
}

.table2 tr:nth-child(4n), .table2 tr:nth-child(4n-1){
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1">
  <tr><td>one</td></tr>
  <tr><td>two</td></tr>
  <tr><td>three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>four</td></tr>
  <tr><td>five</td></tr>
  <tr><td>six</td></tr>
  <tr><td>seven</td></tr>
  <tr><td>eight</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="table2">
  <tr><td>one</td></tr>
  <tr><td>two</td></tr>
  <tr><td>three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>four</td></tr>
  <tr><td>five</td></tr>
  <tr><td>six</td></tr>
  <tr><td>seven</td></tr>
  <tr><td>eight</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: almost there but the highlights is in the wrong rows  for table2 class. it should be 3,4 then 7,8.

Comment: instead of posting a new answer you can accept this answer as accepted answer @ladycoder

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with via changing the color of 1st instead of 2 and 3rd.

```css
p {
  background: red;
}
p:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The eight paragraph.</p>
<p>The ninth paragraph.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
```

Comment: I have two options to highlight the rows, the first(image sample) list will only highlight the rows alternately if I select the Capital. The second list(image sample) if I select Country and Capital then it will highlight alternately every 2 rows. How can I  dynamically set that since they are the same list but different number of rows to highlights which depends on the selected option?. Sorry I am new to css and angular. Thanks

Comment: when is nothing selected you have to work with css sudo class "Odd" & "Even", and once you select the Capital you have to add class to parent div and work with the demo i pasted all the rows color will be red and change the color of the first row to white. this way you will be able to get the desire output.

Answer (score 0):

Use nth-child of CSS for alternate colors for 2 rows.

```
tr:nth-child(4n), tr:nth-child(4n-1) {
    background: red;
}
tr:nth-child(4n-2), tr:nth-child(4n-3) {
    background: blue;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuvkhw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have two options to highlight the rows, the first(image sample) list will only highlight the rows alternately if I select the Capital. The second list(image sample) if I select Country and Capital then it will highlight alternately every 2 rows. How can I  dynamically set that since they are the same list but different number of rows to highlights?. Sorry I am new to css and angular. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, in a *ngFor you can get a variable, even or odd, or index, see [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index;let even=even"
   [style.backgroundcolor]="capital?'even?'red':'white':(i%4)<2'red':'white'">
     <td (click)="capital=false">{{item.country}}</td>
     <td (click)="capital=true">{{item.capital}}</td>
     ...
</tr>

//where you has defined a variable
 capital:boolean=false;
```